# iPad App with three different WebViews?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uiwebview

consider the following function:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    NSURL *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"index" withExtension:@"html"];
    [self.DC70WebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]];
}
```

Where as DC70WebView is a property of class UIWebView tagged to a ViewController.

My problem is, that I have multiple index.html. First this worked, because there was only one directory. Now I am having the following structure:

Devices/index.html
Devices/DC-70
Devices/TE7

and so on. Each Folder in this directory has it's own little presentation with it's own index.html. In the first index.html should be images as links to DC-70/index.html, TE7/index.html, and so on.

My thoughts now where that there are two solutions, but I couldn't get any of this to work:
1: Use the index.html and use images as links so I can just link the Presentations to this. But I don't know what to write into the `a href="??"`. 
2: Use a new ViewController and use buttons(images as backgrounds) to perform segues to my different WebViews.

The problem with 2: is that I THINK I would need to use different Bundles, but I just can't figure out how to use those bundles. I would like to use method 2, as it seems a little cleaner to me, but method 1 is also really fine.

Could someone give me a starting point on this? It is highly appreciated. I think I don't need to say, that I am a beginner in objective-c. I read through like 100 forums but I just couldn't get it done.

Thanks really much in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main thing you should know is that you can't have multiple files in your bundle with the same name even if you put them in different directories cause when your code is compiled and converted to an ipa, all your bundle resources will be in the same folder.

What I suggest is that you name your html files with different names e.g. DC-70Index.html
TE7Index.html

Then you can have as you said multiple buttons in your first view controller which takes the user to a second view controller where you pass the device name and the second view controller can build the html file name and load it into the UIWebView

```
NSString* fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@Index", self.deviceName];
```

If you don't know how to do the above stuff, tell me to edit my answer and specify what's the difficult part.

Comment: I already found out, that I have to rename all my files, but because of you I now know why that is so. Thank you! Renaming my .html I guess I also need to have unique names for images, javascript data, etc, right? One question: what is the bundle for? I thought this could be the solution to have different "directories" inside one .ipa? The solution to use different names for EVERY data is okay, but much work, as I just want to copy my presentations and just change the infos. So I would also have to change EVERY link inside.

Comment: This is from Apple's docs

An NSBundle object represents a location in the file system that groups code and resources that can be used in a program. NSBundle objects locate program resources, dynamically load and unload executable code, and assist in localization. You build a bundle in Xcode using one of these project types: Application, Framework, plug-ins.

Comment: And adding files to the application adds them to the mainBundle which you can access through [NSBundle mainBundle]

Comment: I will mark my answer as answered and for now just use the different file names, BUT for the future: so it is possible to bundle resources like i want to into one "group" and then just open files in that group through different ui web views with different bundles?

Comment: Yes but then you can load the resource like this and of course this is loading from the main bundle but you can load like this from any NSBundle object you have

NSString* filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"index" ofType:@"html"];
    NSString* fileContent = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
    [webView loadHTMLString:fileContent baseURL:nil];